# Insert data to Database by using Model edmx

Tags: c#, database, model

I create Database in visual studio as service-based Database after I make tables i tried to connect it to Model .edmx by choose update Model from Database 
now when I insert data to Model .edmx , it didn't insert it to Database how to make it insert data to Database by using Model and Thanks 
I am using Visual Studio 2010

some code:

```
  private  CoffeeShopDatabaseEntities1 cse = new CoffeeShopDatabaseEntities1();
    private Byte[] bytedata;
    public addproduct()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cbocatgrey.DataSource = cse.TblProductType.ToList();
        cbocatgrey.DisplayMember = "Descrption";
        cbocatgrey.ValueMember = "ProductType";
    }

    private void upload_image_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dlg = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (dlg == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            bytedata = new Byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length);
            fs.Close();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytedata);
            pload.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

        }
    }

    private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TblProduct product = new TblProduct();
        product.Descrption = descrptiontxt.Text;
        product.Price = decimal.Parse(pricetxt.Text);
        product.Image = bytedata;
        product.ProductType = (int)cbocatgrey.SelectedValue;
        cse.AddtoTBlProduct(product);
        cse.saveChanges();


    }
```

Comment: do you have you connection string right? if it didn't insert into the Database, where did it insert? do you have some code sample, error perhaps?

Comment: .edmx is not storing data, definitely issue is in your code... refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941892/what-is-the-purpose-of-edmx-files

Comment: can you show us your code for how you are trying to do things.

Comment: i put code now plz check it